# Unable to set State of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm calling an API using the fetch API inside my react component to set the state. This is my code.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fullName: null, uid: null };

  }
  componentWillMount(){

    fetch(url)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
              response.status);
            return;
          }

          response.json().then(function(data) {
            this.setState( fullName = data.first.givenName + " " + data.lastName,
              uid =data.uid );
          });
        }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"> {this.state.fullName}</a>
          </div>


          <div className="brand-right">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">UID: {this.state.yguid} </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

I can't seem to understand why setState is not working. If I console.log(data) inside the then block, it outputs the correct data, but then fails in the next line. How can I do this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass in `then` is not binded to current context, that cause `this` inside your callback function to be undefined rather than reference your component instance. Just use `bind(this)` to bind the callback with component like this:

```
.then(function () {
  // function body
}.bind(this));
```

or you can use arrow function, which binds the context implicitly:

```
.then(() => {
  // function body
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `this` which you use under `fetch` is not same as the `this` under the class `MyComponent`.

Try to use `arrow functions`

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
        response.status);
      return;
    }

    response.json().then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        fullName: data.first.givenName + " " + data.lastName,
        uid: data.uid,
      });
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to *set* a state is passing the state as an *Object*. Eg.:

```
this.setState({
  fullName: data.first.givenName + " " + data.lastName,
  uid: data.uid
});
```